# Can multiple Boolean variables and equations be converted to a single integer variable and multiple modulo equations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

e.g. let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{B}$ (Boolean)  and $w \in \mathbb{Z}$ (integers)  and $p,q,r \in \mathbb{P}$ (primes)

For $x$ let $(0,1)$ be represented by integers $(\overline{a},a)$ mod p

For $y$ let $(0,1)$ be represented by integers $(\overline{b},b)$ mod q

For $z$ let $(0,1)$ be represented by integers $(\overline{c},c)$ mod r

The Boolean relationships could be translated as:

$(w-\overline{a})(w-a) \equiv 0$ mod $p$

$(w-\overline{b})(w-b) \equiv 0$ mod $q$

$(w-\overline{c})(w-c) \equiv 0$ mod $r$

A logical AND equation could be translated as:

$x \wedge y = True \Longrightarrow (w-a)(w-b) \equiv 0$ mod $pq$

Is there a way to represent an OR equation wrt to $w$?

$x \vee y = True \Longrightarrow ?$

--- Edit ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

A little experimenting:

$y = \overline{x} \Longrightarrow  (w-a)(w-\overline{b}) + (w-\overline{a})(w-b) \equiv (\overline{a}-a)(b-\overline{b}) $ mod $pq$

This is not a sufficient condition but it is a necessary condition.

An inverter is a key building block.

------------------- Summary ----------------------------------------------

Thanks to @Rob Arthan and @user326210 I think I have a working solution.

The objective is to transform multiple Boolean variables and multiple Boolean equations
into one integer variable and multiple modulo equations (focusing on 3 SAT).

Let the Boolean variables be $x_k \in \mathbb{B}$.

The equation $x_k^2 = x_k$ ensures that $x_k = 0 \ or \ 1$

For each $x_k$ let there be a variable $a_k$ and unique prime $p_k$such that:

$x_k \equiv a_k$ mod $p_k$

Let $w \in \mathbb{Z}$. be an integer such that:

$a_k \equiv w$ mod $p_k$

The Boolean equation $x_k^2 = x_k$ is transformed to:

$w^2 \equiv w$ mod $p_k$

The NOT operation is given by:

$\overline{a_k} \equiv 1-a_k \equiv 1-w$ mod $p_k$

Translating an  AND equation $x_1 \wedge x_2 \wedge \overline{x_3}$ :

Consider the term $p_2 p_3 w + p_1 p_3w + p_1 p_2 (1-w)$ mod $p_1 p_2 p_3$

When a variable does not solve the AND equation its term drops out ($\equiv 0$ mod $p_1 p_2 p_3$).

When it is a solution it leaves a residue e.g. $p_2 p_3,  p_1 p_3, p_1 p_2$.

$p_2 p_3 w + p_1 p_3w + p_1 p_2 (1-w) \equiv p_2 p_3  + p_1 p_3 + p_1 p_2 $ mod $p_1 p_2 p_3$

Variables are translated to $w$ , inverted variables $\overline{x_k}$ are translated to $(1-w)$.

Translating an OR equations $x_1 \vee x_2 \vee \overline{x_3}$:

Consider the term $p_2 p_3 w + p_1 p_3w + p_1 p_2 (1-w)$ mod $p_1 p_2 p_3$

When a variable does not solve the OR equation its term drops out ($\equiv 0$ mod $p_1 p_2 p_3$).

When it is a solution it leaves a residue e.g. $p_2 p_3,  p_1 p_3, p_1 p_2$.

There are 7 combinations of residues to have one or more solutions $r_1 \dots r_7$.

Let $t = \alpha w + \beta $  represent the term ...

The OR equation is translated to:

$(t-r_1) \dots (t-r_7) \equiv 0$ mod $p_1 p_2 p_3$

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then your plan is to represent the combination $(x,y,z)$ as a single residue $w$ modulo $pqr$, using the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: Yes. I want to convert 3 SAT problems to modulo equations in one variable $w$.

Comment: x @arthur: That sounds hard -- any polynomial equation you can write modulo $pq$ will be satisfied exactly if it holds both modulo $p$ and modulo $q$, so there seems to be no real way to make the values of $x$ and $y$ interact using only ring operations.

Comment: x @Henning Makholm - I've tried combinations such as: $q(w-a) + p(w-b) \equiv 0$ mod $pq$ , to knock out part of the equation under the single prime modulo but I haven't solved it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you're doing with this notation, but perhaps the following boolean identity will help:

$$a \vee b = \overline{\overline{a}\wedge \overline{b}} $$

Here is a related question which might also help: can you start with a collection of boolean variables $x_1, \ldots, x_k$ and a boolean formula $\varphi(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k)$, then convert the formula into an equivalent formula $\psi(n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_k)$ whose solutions are analogous (with the obvious correspondence that $0\leftrightarrow \mathtt{true}, 1\leftrightarrow \mathtt{false}$)?

For example, the boolean formula might be $\varphi(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (x_1\wedge x_2) \vee \overline{x_3}$ and you want an integer formula $\psi$ which has the same solutions.

To convert a boolean formula $\varphi$ into an integer equation $\psi$, you only need to perform the following substitutions:

$$\begin{align*}
a \wedge b \quad\longrightarrow\quad& a\cdot b\\
a \vee b \quad\longrightarrow\quad& a + b - a\cdot b\\
\overline{a} \quad\longrightarrow\quad& (1-a)\\
\end{align*}$$

(This is called *arithmetization*.)  Finally, if you want to ensure that there are no "extra" solutions (that is, if you want to force all of the integer variables to take on values of 0 and 1), you can also require the equations:

$$x_i^2 = x_i$$

for each of the variables $x_i$.

Comment: I want one variable on the right hand side (translated equations).

Comment: @arthur: so combine user326210's idea with the chinese remainder theorem to represent a vector $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ of 0's and 1's as a single integer whose remainder modulo the $i$-th prime is $a_i$.

Comment: _ @Rob Arthan - So let $w$ be the integer then $a_k \equiv w$ mod $p_k$ and $a_{k}^2 = a_k$ becomes $w^2 \equiv w$ mod $p_k$ to enforce Boolean values. Thanks Rob and user326210.

Comment: _ @Rob Arthan - Also $\overline{a_k} \equiv 1 - a_k \equiv 1 - w$ mod $p_k$